# Regex Substitution with only a fraction of string known

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have a string with contains `\r\nexports.host = "192.168.24.76"` The IP address here is not fixed and is variable.

I want to use regex to find this expression and replace the IP address in bash.

For example, make this `\r\nexports.host = "192.168.24.77"` and then change this to `\r\nexports.host = "192.168.24.78"` in the next iteration. Is there anyway I can do this with regex in a bash script?

For now, I am doing it like: `sed -i -e 's/"192.168.24.76"/"'$1'"/g' ./dist/config.*.js` but just found out that the initial IP address will not be static and can be any value

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v new_ip="your_new_ip" '
match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/){
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) new_ip substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH);
  next
}
1' Input_file
```

In case you want to save output's value into Input_file itself then append `> temp_file  && mv temp_file Input_file` to above code too.